# Etale Ring Homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Let $R$ be a complete ( not sure if it's neccessary) DVR together with a ring $h: \mathbb{Z} \to R$ and $p \in \mathbb{P}$ a prime number.

Let $f: R \to S$ a **finite** ring homomorphism. We assume two things:

- we identify $p$ in $R$  with it's image $h(p)$. Assume $p \in R^{\times}$, so $p$ is invertible in $R$

If we forget the multiplicative structure on $S$ then $f$ endows $S$ with $R$-module structure.

- we assume that $S$ considered as $R$-module is **free** of rank $p^r$, with $r \ge 1$.

**Question**: Do (and if yes why) these two assumption imply that $S$ is **etale** over $R$ (= $f$ is etale map)?

Clearly $S$ is flat over $R$. Why is it also unramified? (recall: etale= flat + ramified). By definition it suffice to show that the discriminant ideal is the unit ideal but I don't see how to show it using the two assumptions. I conjecture that it can be proved (how) that the discriminant ideal contains $p$, but it's only my conjecture. Possibly there is a differently other way to show the claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S=\Bbb{Z}_3[3^{1/2}],\qquad R=\Bbb{Z}_3$$$

Comment: yes, I (probably) see why. It's ramified exactly in every prime $\mathfrak{p} \subset S$ with $\sqrt{3} \in \mathfrak{p}$ since none prime $\mathfrak{q} \subset R$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$ hit $\sqrt{3}$. that's the point, right?

Comment: Those are DVR there is only one prime to check : $(3^{1/2}),(3)$